# How can I insert an image or icon before or after my list items in an html file?

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Hanieh jannesari</title>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul li {
      background-image: url ('tiny. gif'/'https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/166034/screenshots/4252718/media/d0338106a8519f3120dd9a3536b95d6b.gif');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1" start="1">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ol>
  <ul type="star">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I decided to insert some icons beside each list item in the `ul`, but unfortunately when I refer it locally to the folder I stored in my system (located in the same directory) and I link it to the http address, it does not work. I wonder what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: You used relative and absolute addressing together. it is wrong. Use from one of them.

Comment: I know that, I wanted to show that I applied both, not together, sperately

Answer (score 1):

You should use before to show your gif before your list.
I insert this but your image is too big, it is better to use icon or svg and with hover give it animate

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  background-image: url ('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/166034/screenshots/4252718/media/d0338106a8519f3120dd9a3536b95d6b.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul li::before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/166034/screenshots/4252718/media/d0338106a8519f3120dd9a3536b95d6b.gif');
  /* with class ModalCarrot ??*/
  /*or absolute*/
  /*a number that's more than the modal box*/
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-position: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Hanieh jannesari</title>

</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1" start="1">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ol>
  <ul type="star">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: tnx for ur response, but I cannot understand why ul li setting come before <!DOCTYPE html> and head? When I run it in here, it works, but when I transfer to vscode run it, it does not work? ya know! I am a beginner, I guess I should have knowledge of Css to see what ya ran, isn't correct?

Comment: and the thing is as ya said images are too big, but when I run it, they are sticked together, and the whole gif cannot be played.

Comment: @HaniehJannesari I used the stack overflow editor, you can insert this style codes in your style tag. you can not see all the size of gif because I have given it a less than size.

Comment: Hello. So you can change the height of `::before` . I edited your post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```css
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
```

to the css works and it will insert the gif in your `ul li` element.

You can see its working example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Hanieh jannesari</title>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul li::before {
      content: '';
      background: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/166034/screenshots/4252718/media/d0338106a8519f3120dd9a3536b95d6b.gif');
      width: 70px;
      height: 80px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 5px;
      z-index: 10;
      background-position: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1" start="1">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ol>
  <ul type="star">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

and if you don't want the gif in the text's left position then you can try out :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Hanieh jannesari</title>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul li {
      content: '';
      background: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/166034/screenshots/4252718/media/d0338106a8519f3120dd9a3536b95d6b.gif');
      width: 70px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      z-index: 10;
      background-position: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1" start="1">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ol>
  <ul type="star">
    <li>color of love</li>
    <li>color of fame</li>
    <li>color of anger</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: most welcome you can mark the answer as `Mark as Answer` so that i can help others also.

Comment: I appreciate your response, the thing is these gifs are played fully next to the the item lists not before them in a smaller size.

Comment: and it turned into huge gaps btw list items.

Comment: @HaniehJannesari i have updated the answer you can check it now...

Comment: If you don't want gif in the left of text and want the text above your gif then you can simply remove the `::before` & `display: inline-block;` tag from the css and change the height to `150px` and add the `margin-top: 10px;` in it......

Comment: @HaniehJannesari I have added the both examples in my answer you can check out...

Answer (score 0):

in case we know JavaScript, we can add function to our html codes, otherwise we should use pseudo lass or  pseudo elements to make that happen. with the help of ::after and ::before tags we can insert any image or icon before any item.